# how to get or retain file upload control value after postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

hi i have usercontrol on which there is one file upload control, user control is inside Tab container which on aspx page.hirarchy is like bellow:

1.Master Page
2.aspx Page having ajax tab control.
3.User control which is inside tab container.
4.file upload control which is on user control. and submit button

Problem i am facing:
When i click on submit button as page load event is called before buttons on click event value of file upload control is getting nulll.

could you please tell me how can i fetch the file upload control value after postback.
thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

The file upload control does not retain the posted file with each request.
When the user selects a file, it will be available in the next PostBack request that occurs.

You should check for a [PostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx) on each postback and save this file on the server.
Keep a reference to its path in the ViewState.
Then you can process the file when the user has finished all inputs.

Comment: in my case when i click on submit button as user control is on apsx page its page load event is getting called and, i am getting null reference.also as i have used tab control and user control is inside tab there is more than one instance of that user control.

Comment: What do you mean by value? If you are refering to the file, if user has uploaded a file, it will be available in the [PostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx) property. If not, this will be null.

Comment: The `Load` event is called on every request. I don't see anything wrong with the  TabControl or being inside a UserControl either.